# iphone sdk: CGAffineTransform not working in iOS 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uialertview, cgaffinetransform

i'm using the following code to move a uialertview with a uitextfield in it. 
The alertView is supposed to slide up when the keyboard appears and slide backdown as soon as it dissappears. The following code worked perfectly fine for me under ios 3.1.2. But for some reason it does not work under ios 4.0..... The issue seems to be the transformation i'm making but i have no idea what exactly is going wrong. It would be great if anyone knows a solution! Thanks in advance! here's my code:

```
- (void)addItemAction{

workoutName = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Workout" message:@"Insert the name of your new workout:\n                " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];
workoutName.cancelButtonIndex = 0;
UITextField *titleField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12.0, 90.0, 260.0, 25.0)];
titleField.delegate = self;
titleField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
titleField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[workoutName addSubview:titleField];
[workoutName show];

}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;

}



- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -70.0);
[workoutName setTransform:myTransform];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
CGAffineTransform myTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);
[workoutName setTransform:myTransform];
[UIView commitAnimations];
if ([textField.text length] != 0) {
    self.newWorkout = textField.text;
}
else {
    self.newWorkout = @"";
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 4 changed the behavior in the UIAlertView making the translation unnecessary.  Try wrapping the translation in an if to test if you are on an iOS version < 4 and only apply it there - that helped the situation we had.

Example:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 4.0) {
    // translation goes here
}
```